# Is it possible for this Iron-Carbon Compound to exist?

Tags: organometallic-compounds

Can this compound be created?
[image]
Where the orange is Iron and the black is Carbon.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No

Long answer: Assuming you had hands tiny enough to manipulate individual atoms, you could make this molecule. The amount of time it would stay together would be as close to 0 as it gets. To start iron can't accommodate that amount of electrons, and the formal charges of this molecule are extreme to say the least.

Comment: Welcome to chemistry.se! If you have questions about how to beautify your posts, have a look at the [help]. Do you want to know more about this site, please take the [tour].

Answer (score 0):

that molecule is not stable.
There exists 
(L)xFe=C(R1)(R2) carben complexes and
(L)xRu=C=C=C=C=Ru(Lx) molecules,
so their might exists also a (L)xRu=C=Ru(L)x or (L)xFe=C=Fe(L)x molecule in theory
but at least the 3 not centered Carben-C-Atom (connected to each Iron atom) have to be stabilized.